# Npm problem, Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I can't uninstall or upgrade npm as i want to do. The problem follows below:

```
    Error: Failed to replace env in config: ${APPDATA}
        at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:415:13
        at String.replace (<anonymous>)
        at envReplace (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:411:12)
        at parseField (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:389:7)
        at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:330:24
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at Conf.add (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:328:23)
        at ConfigChain.addString (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\config-chain\index.js:244:8)
        at Conf.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:316:10)
        at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:115:16
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
        at exit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:97:27)
        at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:216:3)
        at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:78:20
        at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:225:22)
        at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:263:24
        at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:81:7
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at Conf.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:80:13)
        at Conf.f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
        at Conf.emit (events.js:223:5)
    C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:97
      var doExit = npm.config.loaded ? npm.config.get('_exit') : true
                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
    at exit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\←[4mnpm←[24m\lib\utils\error-handler.js:97:27)
    at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\←[4mnpm←[24m\lib\utils\error-handler.js:216:3)
←[90m    at process.emit (events.js:223:5)←[39m
←[90m    at process._fatalException (internal/process/execution.js:150:25)←[39m
```

I read the docs and i didn't find something that worked. I tried to remove the file .npmrc, but it doesn't exist in the directory.

Comment: Same issue here for me

Comment: I copy and erased the file `.npmrc ` in `.../Program FIles/.../npm/.npmrc` and put in `.../AppData/.../npm/`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

For me it was solved my just installing create-react-app package and then using that package to create react application

```
npm i -g create-react-app
```

and then using `create-react-app` to create application

```
create-react-app mern-app
```